# How can I reduce the trigger area for my drop-down navigation?

Tags: css

My drop-down menu on this page: http://newdawnts.org/ is triggering when the user hovers over the slideshow (non-displayed list items). How can I change the code so that so that the sub-menu is only triggered when the user hovers over only the main menu navigation items.

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML markup within your post rather than linking to an outside resource.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to fix the problem on my browser. Can you check if it's solving your problem. You dropdown menu has `visibility: visible` applied to it. You need to change that to `hidden`.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```